# Mac Setup to Test Applications in Every Possible Browser?

Tags: windows, macos, browser, cross-browser

What is the simplest/most-streamlined setup for testing apps in all of todays browsers?

- Safari 2, 3, 4 (and versions in between)
- Firefox 1, 2, 3 (and sub versions)
- IE 6, 7, 8, 9
- Opera 8, 9, 10
- Chrome

Is there some sort of program like the [Ruby Version Manager (RVM)](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/basics/) that allows you to install browsers at different versions and then just lists all the ones you have installed like this:

- Internet Explorer 6
- Internet Explorer 7
- Safari 3.2
- Safari 4.4
  ...

And you can just click it from there and it opens.  Something like that would be very helpful.

The main things I would like to streamline in my browser-compatibility workflow are:

1. Installing all the browsers I can think of and every version that's been known to cause problems.
2. Being able to easily find them and open them.
3. Being able to test Internet Explorer on a Mac without running Windows (Parallels or VMWare).

Also, is there an Internet Explorer application for the mac so I don't have to use Parallels or VMWare Fusion (which are pretty heavy for running on a laptop while developing at the same time, running tests, etc).

Thanks!

Comment: When you're testing for cross-browser compatibility `platform` is a factor not to be neglected. So I would definitely virtualize and run IE 6,7 under Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s not a way to have multiple Safari version on one Mac, especially not if you want to simulate real-world conditions. For that you’ll have to have multiple Macs or use [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org) to emulate Mac OS X.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just wanting to see how the pages *look* (I expect you want more fully featured testing than this but I figured I'd provide what I know) then I suggest checking out [browsershots](http://browsershots.org/).

Apart from that, I know Adobe BrowserLab ([link](https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html)) is pretty fully featured to do what you're talking about. I've never used it, but have planned to sit down one weekend and try it out.

Comment: I upvote for adobe browserlab. Been using it for quite sometime and it works just great.